# new line character in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, newline

I add new line character '
' between two string in xslt file like this:

```
test &#10; test1
```

Output is just like this:

```
test
test1
```

But I want output to be just like this:

```
test &#10; test1
```

Is that possible in xslt?

I think I should talking about why I want this:

the first output doesn't make effect in excel's Alt + Enter's. But when I manually edit xml like output2, it works. &#10; also doesn't work.

**Extra Explaination**

Let's imagine 'test test1' is written inside an excel cell.  When i use Alt + Enter inside this and open file with notpead++, i see this cell like this:

```
test&#10;test1
```

In xslt file I try to replace all "newline" text with "
" to make this effect. But when I open this output in notpead i see that:

```
test
test1
```

but I want output to be like that:

```
test&#10;test1
```

Comment: The two are semantically identical, so why does it cause you an issue?

Comment: Maybe `test &amp;#10;` test1` is what you want?

Comment: the first output doesn't make effect in excel's Alt + Enter's. But when I manually edit xml like output2, it works. &amp;#10; also doesn't work.

Comment: As @Rowland alluded to, any correct XML parser should treat `&#10;` and a literal line feed as the same character. So you shouldn't need to worry about whether your output has a literal line feed or a `&#10;`. And I don't understand what you mean by "doesn't make effect in excel's Alt + Enter's". How are you feeding the XML input into Excel?

Comment: @LarsH I added some extra note. I think it's clear now.

Comment: OK... why do you want to see `&#10;` in Notepad++? If it's supposed to be XML, then it shouldn't matter... the two are equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are manipulating some xml nodes via templates then we can implement like ...

```
       <xsl:template match="node">
                <xsl:text>Package: </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="childNode"/>
                <xsl:text> available from </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="OtherchildNOde"/>
                <xsl:text>&lt;br/&gt; </xsl:text>
        </xsl:template>
```

so main thing is [  <br/>   ]. we can use p tag  instead of br tag  also.

Comment: <xsl:text>&lt;br/&gt; </xsl:text>

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:-

```
<xsl:text>test &#10; test1 </xsl:text>
```

Comment: The result of that should be `test &amp;#10; test1` which is not what the OP wanted.

Comment: It should now give semantically correct output, but it doesn't do anything different from what the OP already had. He wants to make sure it's serialized a certain way. Maybe you meant `<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="true">test &amp;#10; test1</xsl:text>`? That would work in some cases where the XSL processor has control over the serialization (but is not guaranteed to work in any case).